# Is there a way to make bevels automatically dissolve vertices?

Tags: bevel

In hard surface modeling, when I use bevels, probably most of the time I don’t use clamp overlap. And I’ve seen in other polygon-based software that it is possible to make nice bevels with some automatic dissolving feature that fixes the problem of having to manually dissolve a lot of vertices in heavy models. Any help?

Comment: Hello :). There's the *Weld modifier* that can procedurally merge vertices close to each other

Comment: Thank you my  friend. That kind of works.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is that you will have to do this before bevelling: Selct your whole mesh by pressing A on your keyboard, and then press M>Merge by Distance. This will dissolve any overlapping verticies, and then you will have good bevels.

Comment: Op spoke about hard surface modeling. In this workflow the modifiers in theory remain not applied so there is no mesh to manually merge. Due to this problem most hard surface designers using Blender are forced to apply the modifiers and fix mesh artifacts manually.

Comment: @FilipFranik I know the modifiers might not be applied. That is why I am saying to make sure the mesh has no overlapping verticies in edit mode so the bevel modefier gives nice bevels.